# ASP.NET - route id to page but in page is null

Tags: asp.net, twitter-bootstrap, razor-pages

I have route problem,

With this markup:

```
<td><a asp-page="./EditNew" asp-route-testId=@Model.TestId asp-route- 
testCaseId=@Model.Id class="btn btn-success">Edit</a></td>
```

when I click on the link, it correctly opens a new bootstrap model in the EditNew page.

But if i add this line to the `a` tag:

```
data-target="#myModal" data-toggle="modal"
```

then `asp-route-testId` and `asp-route-testCaseId` are sent to `OnGet()` as `testId=null` and `testCaseId=0`.

If i remove `data-target="#myModal" data-toggle="modal"`
it all works fine.

Why can't I have the `data-target` & `data-toggle` attributes in the link?

Comment: I don't quite understand what you're asking, is it okay if I edit the question to what I _think_ you're asking?

Answer (score 1):

I think you are trying to mix Asp.Net and bootstrap in a way that can't work.

If you want to show the EditNew markup in a modal dialog using bootstrap, then just put the razor tags for `@Model.Id` and `@Model.TestId` straight into your modal dialog markup.

Let's use the code from https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/modal/ for this example. Notice that I've put the `@Model.Id` and `@Model.TestId` straight into the markup:

```
<!-- Button trigger modal -->
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">
  Launch demo modal
</button>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" >Id is @Model.Id and TestCase Id @Model.TestId</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        ...
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Why?**

Because razor tags like `@Model.TestId` are evaluated *when the markup is generated* before the page loads. So they **can** be embedded in the markup but they **can't** be evaluated again after the page has loaded.

Google asp.net razor get started for more.

Comment: thanks,
how i can to TestCase Id with another page (EditNew)

Comment: That's what you already have in your question, I thought? If you don't use the modal dialog then your `<a asp-page="EditNew" asp-route-testId=@Model.TestId asp-route- 
testCaseId=@Model.Id class="btn btn-success">Edit</a>` takes you to the EditNew page with route parameters?